# read and write file with newline php

Tags: php

I have a php file with the following info

```
One
Two
Three
```

Now i want to split them into an array, so i used:

```
   $filehandle = fopen($filename, 'rb');
  $line_of_text = fgets($filehandle);
  $array = explode("\n", $line_of_text);
```

But it is not working.

They are written in the file like this:

```
    $filehandle = fopen($textfile, 'a');
    fputs($filehandle, $line . "\r\n");
    fclose($filehandle);
```

So how do i read them into an array?.

Thanks.

Comment: just curious, have you read manual page for the function you used?

Comment: Yeah i did, i guess i missed a part sorry about that. By the way, how do i write an array to a file `foreach ($array as $index => $waarde)
        {
        
        fputs($fh, $waarde . "\r\n");
            
            
        }` does not seem to work.

Comment: @1ntello that should work, but you can also pass an array directly to [`file_put_contents()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) although the elements will need to already have the CRLF sequence on the end. If your above code does not work, make sure you opened `$fh` in write mode (`$fh = fopen($filename,'w');`), and that your `$array` actually contains some data.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for [`file()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php). However, it should be noted that this will leave all your array elements with a trailing CRLF sequence on them.

Alternatively (all these will strip the trailing CRLF):

```
$array = explode("\r\n", file_get_contents($filename));
```

...or...

```
$fp = fopen($filename, 'r');
$filecontents = fread($fp, filesize($filename));
$array = explode("\r\n", $filecontents);
```

...or...

```
$fp = fopen($filename, 'r');
$array = array();
while (($line = fgets($fp)) !== FALSE) $array[] = trim($line);
```

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel Sorry, wrong type of quotes, just spotted it and fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function

> file — Reads entire file into an array

```
$your_array = file ("filename", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); // add the flag to strip newlines
```